# Starter query about lag

Tags: python, pygame, delay, lag

Okay. My problem is, when i run my code it delays everything else than the moving function when you click a or d. Like the ball that flys from the sky, that just stops moving for while. How do i fix it?
Here is my making the screen code:

```
import pygame as py
import os
import time

NÄYTTÖX = 900
NÄYTTÖY = 675
```

Here are colors:

```
SKY_BLUE = (0, 128, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
```

Here is making players part:

```
PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA = 100
syötävä_halkaisija = 20

SCREEN = py.display.set_mode((NÄYTTÖX, NÄYTTÖY))
PELAAJA = py.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "packman.png"))
PELAAJA = py.transform.rotate(py.transform.scale(PELAAJA, (PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA, 
PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA)), 90)
```

Here i make my background:

```
TAUSTA = py.transform.scale(py.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "space.png")), (NÄYTTÖX, 
NÄYTTÖY))
```

Here i draw everything on the screen:

```
def piirto(syötävärect, pelaajarect):
    SCREEN.blit(TAUSTA, (0, 0))
    SCREEN.blit(PELAAJA, (pelaajarect.x, pelaajarect.y))
    py.draw.circle(SCREEN, GREEN, (syötävärect.x, syötävärect.y), syötävä_halkaisija)
    py.display.update()
```

This is the main function:

```
def main():

    pelaajarect = py.Rect(NÄYTTÖX / 2 - PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA / 2, NÄYTTÖY - PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA * 
1.7, PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA, PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA)
    syötävärect = py.Rect(NÄYTTÖX / 2, 0, syötävä_halkaisija, syötävä_halkaisija)

    clock = py.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in py.event.get():
            if event.type == py.QUIT:
                run = False
```

Here is  my key codes:

```
            if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == py.K_a:
                    if pelaajarect.x == 400 or pelaajarect.x == 600:
                        for i in range(100):
                            pelaajarect.x -= 2
                            piirto(syötävärect, pelaajarect)
                            time.sleep(0.0007)
                elif event.key == py.K_d:
                    if pelaajarect.x == 400 or pelaajarect.x == 200:
                        for i in range(100):
                            pelaajarect.x += 2
                            piirto(syötävärect, pelaajarect)
                            time.sleep(0.0007)
```

This makes the ball on the sky falling forever:

```
        if syötävärect.y < NÄYTTÖY:
            syötävärect.y += 2
        else:
            syötävärect.y = 0
```

Here is everything else:

```
        piirto(syötävärect, pelaajarect)
    py.quit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So it doesn't work. I use VScode studios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never try to control the application with a loop inside the application loop. Use the application loop and change the position of object in each frame:

Add a variable `target_x`. Set the variable in the event loop and move the object to the target in the application loop:

```py
def main():

    pelaajarect = py.Rect(NÄYTTÖX / 2 - PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA / 2, NÄYTTÖY - PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA * 
1.7, PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA, PELAAJA_HALKAISIJA)
    syötävärect = py.Rect(NÄYTTÖX / 2, 0, syötävä_halkaisija, syötävä_halkaisija)

    # init target None
    target_x = None

    clock = py.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in py.event.get():
            if event.type == py.QUIT:
                run = False


            if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == py.K_a:
                    if pelaajarect.x == 400 or pelaajarect.x == 600:
                        # set target position
                        target_x = pelaajarect.x + 200
                        
                elif event.key == py.K_d:
                    if pelaajarect.x == 400 or pelaajarect.x == 200:
                        # set target position
                        target_x = pelaajarect.x - 200
               
        # move to target position       
        if target_x != None:
            if pelaajarect.x < target_x:
                pelaajarect.x += 2
            elif pelaajarect.x > target_x:
                pelaajarect.x -= 2
                        
        if syötävärect.y < NÄYTTÖY:
            syötävärect.y += 2
        else:
            syötävärect.y = 0

         piirto(syötävärect, pelaajarect)
    py.quit()
```